# VBScript works great when I run it from command prompt but not from within Inno Setup

Tags: vbscript, inno-setup

I have a VBScript that I wrote that works great!  It does everything that I need it to perfectly when I run it from a command line in Windows 10.

```
cscript.exe "C:\SetupTempPath\MyScript.vbs" "First Param" 1234 "Third Param"
```

For some reason when I have it in my Inno Setup script...

```
Filename: "{sys}\cscript.exe"; \
  Parameters: """{tmp}\MyScript.vbs"" ""{code:GetStringValue}"" {#PORT} ""{#NAME}"""; \
  Description: "Set port to {#PORT}."; \
  StatusMsg: "Setting the port to {#PORT}."; \
  Tasks: setPortNumber; \
  Check: SetTcpPort({#PORT});
```

When I run setup in debug mode, it shows me the following...

```
[12:37:45.377] -- Run entry --
[12:37:45.378] Run as: Current user
[12:37:45.380] Type: Exec
[12:37:45.381] Filename: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe
[12:37:45.425] Parameters: "C:\SetupTempPath\MyScript.vbs" "First Param" 1234 "Third Param"
[12:38:04.987] Process exit code: 0
[12:38:04.995] Need to restart Windows? No
[12:38:06.944] Deinitializing Setup.
[12:38:06.997] *** Setup exit code: 0
```

So as you can see everything is getting resolved successfully from code functions as well as Inno Setup constants (Definitions) that are defined.

I ended up putting a bunch of MsgBox lines in the VBScript to check the status and see when it errors out.  I ended up finding out the part of the VBScript that it has an issue with (only when being ran from Inno Setup) so I adjusted the script to account for some error control and here is the results...

```
Set wmiComputer = GetObject(wmiObjectQuery)
Set tcpProperties = wmiComputer.ExecQuery(wmiQuery)

MsgBox "Break! Count: " & tcpProperties.Count
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Query returned no results.", 0, "Port not changed!"
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

Stepping through it EVERYTHING is exactly the same.  The `wmiObjectQuery` string is the same, the `wmiQuery` I create is the same.  I found no differences at all except **ONE**.  When `ExecQuery()` is called and I'm running it from a command prompt (while setup is waiting for me to close it), it returns **TWO** records.  On the other hand, when I let setup try and run it, that ends up tripping the error control because `tcpProperties.Count` fails (due to tcpProperties NOT being set).

So my question is, why does it work perfectly from a command prompt and not the Inno Setup script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess: Inno Setup executes 32-bit `cscript`. While on command-line, you execute 64-bit `cscript`. That can make the difference.

Try adding the [`Flags: 64bit`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=64bit) to your `[Run]` entry.

---

The Inno Setup installer is 32-bit application, so it will by default find 32-bit version of `cscript` (`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript`).

See also [Install Mode: 32-bit vs. 64-bit](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls) article in Inno Setup documentation.